# Is it possible to copy game/app groups from one profile to another?

Tags: xbox-one

I created a few game/app groups under one of my kids' profiles to help "organize" the games and apps which they are allowed to use. However, I wasn't really paying close enough attention because I *thought* I was creating them under the "main" user. I spent several minutes organizing everything because I mistakenly thought I'd be looking at the setup every time I hit the Xbox button. Of course, the next time I got on the Xbox, all of the pins and such were missing and I realized what I had done.

So, as the title question asks, is there a "quick and easy" way to copy a game/app group I created (*with all of its shortcuts*) under one profile on my Xbox One to the other profiles so I don't have to go waste time doing it again?